# ODBC connectivity for Azure Purview

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-data-catalog, azure-purview

Azure Data Catalog gen1 allowed us to get metadata from tables inside a Databricks workspace, by using ODBC connection.  Do we have have ODBC connectivity for Azure Purview too?  If so, can someone share the details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unfortunately, ODBC connectivity for Azure Purview is not supported.

**Reference:** [Supported data sources and file types in Azure Purview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/purview/sources-and-scans)

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/932437-azure-purview

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.